# Sping Boot Microservice

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, microservices

**1st approach**

Implement the user profile in every micro service.

**2nd approach: user profile service**

Implement the user profile check in a single micro service.

What are other factors I might consider when making a decision? What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you haven't mentioned yet another approach which I actually can recommend to consider:

Introduce the gateway - a special service that will take care of authorization / authentication between the "outer word" and your backend services:

```
Client ---> Gateway -----> Service 1
                   |-----> Service 2
                   ...
```

It will be impossible to directly access Service1, 2, etc from the "Outer world" directly, only the gateway will be exposed, it will also take care of routing.
On the other hand, all the requests coming to the backend will be considered to be already authorized (might have additional headers with the "verified" roles list, or use some "standard" technology like JWT)

Besides the separation of concerns (backend services "think" only about the business logic implementation), this approach has the following benefits:

- All the logic in one place, easy to fix, upgrade, etc. For example, your  first approach might suffer from more advanced ecosystem (what if Services are written in different languages, using different frameworks, etc) - you'll have to re-implement the AuthZ in different technology stacks.
- The user is not "aware" of all the variety of the services ( only the gateway is an entry-point, the routing is done in the gateway).
- Doesn't have "redundant" calls (read CPU / Memory / IO) by backend services for the authZ. Compare with the second presented approach - you'll have to call external service upon each request.
- You can scale the authZ service (gateway) and backend services separately.
  For example, if you introduce new service you don't have to think how much overhead it will introduce to your AuthZ component (redis, database, etc). So you can scale it out only by business requirements

Comment: 0.25Mb per call is quite a lot of data actually... AFAIK, the authorization data can be presented with way less bytes (like Groups names / ids, permissions, etc - all are small strings), so I might be missing something here